Utilizing Python script with large number of dependencies in a Lambda Function
I am attempting to execute a program using an AWS Lambda function with layers and triggers in AWS GovCloud. However, I am facing a memory error during the process of uploading a ZIP file containing the Python environment with the necessary modules and imports.
Key Points:
Environment Setup: The Python environment file was created using Docker and then copied from the Docker image to my local machine.
File Size Issue: The resulting file size of the environment exceeds the accepted limit for Lambda layers.
Module Separation
Attempt: I tried to separate the required modules, but even with only OpenCV included, I still encountered memory issues.
AWS GovCloud Constraints: Operating within AWS GovCloud adds complexity, as many Python imports are not pre-included.
Challenge: Finding a solution to implement Lambda functions with complex programs and numerous dependencies in AWS GovCloud, given the constraints on file size and memory
Environment Creation:
Created the Python environment file using Docker.
Copied the environment from the Docker image to my local machine.
File Size Issue:
The resulting file size of the environment exceeded the accepted limit for Lambda layers.
Module Separation Attempt:
Attempted to separate the required modules to reduce the file size.
Created a ZIP file containing only the OpenCV module.
Despite this effort, I still encountered memory issues during the upload.
What I Expected:
Expectation:
Expected the ZIP file containing the Python environment and necessary modules to upload successfully to AWS Lambda layers without exceeding the size limit.
Function Execution:
Expected the Lambda function to execute the program correctly with all required dependencies in place.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

It's my general expectation that if you're operating within increased limitations, generally speaking, less is going to be possible. You might look at using ECS containers & running them on demand to do what you need. You can put whatever you need into the container to do whatever it is you need to do. Lambda also has the ability to run containers.

Thank you! This is very helpful and is an avenue i will look into.
